# Existe alguma maneira de eliminar elementos duplicados que não sejam exatamente iguais?

Tags: r

```
dados1 <- c("10 ANOS DA POLÍTICA NACIONAL DE PROMOÇÃO DA SAÚDE: TRAJETÓRIAS E DESAFIOS", "4-CYCLOPROPYL-1-(1-METHYL-4-NITRO-1H-IMIDAZOL-5-YL)-1H-1,2,3-TRIAZOLE AND ETHYL 1-(1-METHYL-4-NITRO-1H-IMIDAZOL-5-YL)-1H-1,2,3-TRIAZOLE-4-CARBOXYLATE","7,7-DIMETHYLAPORPHINE AND OTHER ALKALOIDS FROM THE BARK OF", "ABSCESSO DO MÚSCULO PSOAS ASSOCIADO À INFECÇÃO POR MYCOBACTERIUM TUBERCULOSIS EM PACIENTE COM AIDS", "ABUNDANCE OF LUTZOMYIA LONGIPALPIS TESTE","ABUNDANCE OF LUTZOMYIA LONGIPALPIS", "ABUSO E DEPENDÊNCIA DE DROGAS NA PERSPECTIVA DA SAÚDE PÚBLICA (EDITORIAL)")

qualis <- c("A2", "B3", "A1", "B2", "A2", "A2", "A1")

m <- data.frame("Título da Produção" = dados1,
                "Qualis" = qualis,
                "Ano" = c(2010:2016))
```

O df acima é apenas ilustrativo. Notem que o quinto e sexto elemento de "dados1" são praticamente a mesma coisa, mas como não estão escritos da mesma maneira não consigo utilizar o duplicated e nem o unique.

Há alguma outra opção para limpar essas linhas, filtrando por parte do nome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz uma função que pode te ajudar. Ela usa o pacote `stringdist` que calcula a distância entre strings:

```
combinar_textos_parecidos <- function(x, max_dist){
  x <- as.character(x)
  distancias <- stringdist::stringdistmatrix(x, x)
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    small_dist <- distancias[i,] < max_dist
    if(sum(small_dist) > 1){
      x[small_dist] <- x[which(small_dist)[1]] 
    }
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Veja o que ela retorna quando aplico no seu vetor `Título.da.Produção`. Agora os itens 5 e 6 possuem exatamente o mesmo nome.

```
combinar_textos_parecidos(m$Título.da.Produção, 10)
[1] "10 ANOS DA POLÍTICA NACIONAL DE PROMOÇÃO DA SAÚDE: TRAJETÓRIAS E DESAFIOS"                                                                            
[2] "4-CYCLOPROPYL-1-(1-METHYL-4-NITRO-1H-IMIDAZOL-5-YL)-1H-1,2,3-TRIAZOLE AND ETHYL 1-(1-METHYL-4-NITRO-1H-IMIDAZOL-5-YL)-1H-1,2,3-TRIAZOLE-4-CARBOXYLATE"
[3] "7,7-DIMETHYLAPORPHINE AND OTHER ALKALOIDS FROM THE BARK OF"                                                                                           
[4] "ABSCESSO DO MÚSCULO PSOAS ASSOCIADO À INFECÇÃO POR MYCOBACTERIUM TUBERCULOSIS EM PACIENTE COM AIDS"                                                   
[5] "ABUNDANCE OF LUTZOMYIA LONGIPALPIS TESTE"                                                                                                             
[6] "ABUNDANCE OF LUTZOMYIA LONGIPALPIS TESTE"                                                                                                             
[7] "ABUSO E DEPENDÊNCIA DE DROGAS NA PERSPECTIVA DA SAÚDE PÚBLICA (EDITORIAL)"
```

Então fazendo:

```
m$Título.da.Produção <- combinar_textos_parecidos(m$Título.da.Produção, 10)
m[!duplicated(m$Título.da.Produção),]
```

A linha 5 seria excluida.

**Obs** usei a distancia 10 como ponto de corte. Talvez você queira ser mais ou menos tolerante com a proximidade das strings. Para isso basta controlar o parâmetro `max_dist` da minha função.

Você pode ler mais sobre o cálculo das distâncias [aqui](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2014-1/loo.pdf) ou digitando `help("stringdist-metrics")` no seu console do R.

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: `dados$Título.da.Produção <- combinar_textos_parecidos(dados$Título.da.Produção, 10)
Error in distancias[i, ] : subscript out of bounds` obrigado.
mas ainda estou tentando entender o problema.

Comment: Esse erro está acontecendo provavelmente pq vc não tem essa coluna no seu banco de dados. Veja o que acontece qundo faço a função de `NULL`: `> combinar_textos_parecidos(NULL, 10)
Error in distancias[i, ] : subscript out of bounds`.