# Limpeza e Padronização de Texto

Tags: string, r

Tenho uma tabela do Excel já no R com duas colunas (código e nome da empresa) e 22 mil linhas. Os nomes foram preenchidos livremente, então o mesmo nome está escrito de diferentes formas, abreviadas e por extenso.

Já consegui transformar tudo para caixa alta, mas preciso transformar os nomes para um único padrão, de forma a não repetir a mesma empresa com descrições diferentes.

Exemplos de situações de descrições diferentes para a mesma empresa:

1. `ADASA/DF`, 
   `ADASA-AGENCIA DE AGUAS`,
   `ADASA-DF`
   Seria transformado para `ADASA`;
2. `CASA CIVIL`, `CASA CIVIL - DF`, `CASA CIVIL DA GOVERNADORIA DF`, `CASA CIVIL DO DF`, `CASA CIVIL DO DF.`, `CASA CIVIL DO DIST. FEDERAL`, `CASA CIVIL DO DISTRITO FEDERAL`, `SEC. ESTADO DA CASA CIVIL`, etc... seria transformado para `CASA CIVIL`.

Pesquisei por perguntas similares no site, mas não encontrei resposta.
Como sou iniciante em programação e em R, talvez não esteja sabendo qual o melhor termo para pesquisar.

Depois de padronizar os textos da coluna "nome da empresa", preciso conseguir como resultado todos os códigos associados àquela empresa, sem repetir o nome da empresa.

Comment: quando vc fala q é iniciante, é iniciante em programação? já pensou em criar uma tabela de conversão utilizando expressões regulares?

Comment: Caro MaviR, acredito que o que queres não é uma tarefa programável sem saberes exatamente qual informação deve ser extraída de cada linha desta tabela. As possibilidades são virtualmente infinitas e efetuar um "DISTINCT" nestas informações, considerando que ela pode estar em qualquer posição do texto e escrita em diversas formas diferentes me parece uma tarefa impossível sem um banco de dados de clientes corretos (o que já seria por si só a correção), também pelo fato de qualquer expressão regular conforme sugerido acima poder gerar falsos positivos.

Comment: Com as informações dadas, acredito que você deva criar uma série de `palavras-chave` que deverão ser encontradas nessa coluna, substituindo todo o restante. Ex: Utilizo a palavra-chave `CASA CIVIL`, procuro todos os registros que a contenham e substituo o valor da coluna por ela.

Comment: Quando você fala que tem uma "base de dados", estás utilizando algum SGBD como MySQL, Oracle, etc... ?

Comment: Acho que uma adaptação do código da seguinte pergunta pode ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/146108/6036

Comment: É claro que essa forma não é tão precisa quanto a criação de uma tabela de palavras-chave.

Comment: @DanielFalbel, vi essa resposta. Mas ela não se aplicaria ao meu caso porque os textos não possuem um início padrão para todos como era o caso dele. Não há uma distância padrão que eu poderia utilizar como base.

Comment: Ela não usa o início para calcular a distância, podem ser coisas no meio da frase...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe um jeito mágico de fazer isso. Vou propor uma forma que talvez possa agilizar o seu trabalho manual, pois em algum momento você terá que conferir e ver quais estão bem classificados ou não.

Com o seguinte código:

```
combinar_textos_parecidos <- function(x, max_dist, method = "lv"){
  x <- as.character(x)
  distancias <- stringdist::stringdistmatrix(x, x, method = method)
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    small_dist <- distancias[i,] < max_dist
    if(sum(small_dist) > 1){
      x[small_dist] <- x[which(small_dist)[1]] 
    }
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Copiado da pergunta linkada e adaptdado para escolher o método de cálculo da distância.

```
library(stringr)
textos %>% str_replace_all("-", " ") %>%
  str_replace_all("[:space:]{1,}", " ") %>%
  combinar_textos_parecidos(0.4, method = "jaccard") 

 [1] "ADASA/DF"               "ADASA AGENCIA DE AGUAS" "ADASA/DF"               "CASA CIVIL"            
 [5] "CASA CIVIL"             "CASA CIVIL"             "CASA CIVIL"             "CASA CIVIL"            
 [9] "CASA CIVIL"             "CASA CIVIL"             "CASA CIVIL"
```

Dessa forma, no seu exemplo você precisaria alterar apenas 1 elemento do seu vetor.

É claro que essa é só uma alternativa. Você também poderia criar uma tabela auxiliar com todas as possíveis empresas e fazer um join usando o pacote `fuzzyjoin`. Por algum motivo o pacote não faz o join quando uma das tabelas tem apenas uma coluna (vou abrir um issue no github), mas já dá pra usar.

Exemplo:

```
textos <- data.frame(emp = c("ADASA/DF",  "ADASA-AGENCIA DE AGUAS", "ADASA-DF",
                                          "CASA CIVIL", "CASA CIVIL - DF", "CASA CIVIL DA GOVERNADORIA DF", "CASA CIVIL DO DF", "CASA CIVIL DO DF.", "CASA CIVIL DO DIST. FEDERAL", "CASA CIVIL DO DISTRITO FEDERAL", "SEC. ESTADO DA CASA CIVIL"),
                     stringsAsFactors = F, a = 1
)

empresas <- data.frame(emp = c("ADASA", "CASA CIVIL"), emp2 = c("ADASA", "CASA CIVIL"), stringsAsFactors = F)
library(fuzzyjoin)
regex_left_join(textos, empresas, by = c(emp = "emp"))

                            emp.x a      emp.y       emp2
1                        ADASA/DF 1      ADASA      ADASA
2          ADASA-AGENCIA DE AGUAS 1      ADASA      ADASA
3                        ADASA-DF 1      ADASA      ADASA
4                      CASA CIVIL 1 CASA CIVIL CASA CIVIL
5                 CASA CIVIL - DF 1 CASA CIVIL CASA CIVIL
6   CASA CIVIL DA GOVERNADORIA DF 1 CASA CIVIL CASA CIVIL
7                CASA CIVIL DO DF 1 CASA CIVIL CASA CIVIL
8               CASA CIVIL DO DF. 1 CASA CIVIL CASA CIVIL
9     CASA CIVIL DO DIST. FEDERAL 1 CASA CIVIL CASA CIVIL
10 CASA CIVIL DO DISTRITO FEDERAL 1 CASA CIVIL CASA CIVIL
11      SEC. ESTADO DA CASA CIVIL 1 CASA CIVIL CASA CIVIL
```